# Arizal was 6 days on a island

Tags: history, arizal

It's [known](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/isaac-ben-solomon-luria) that the Arizal was on an island for 6 days a week and only came home on Shabbosim. Is there a Shuir/Sefer/Tradition that states what the Arizal did during his days on the island? Was he doing Hisbodidus? Learning Gemara? Zohar? Chill?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105851/discussion-between-moshe-and-kouty).

Answer (score 4):

If you trust the linked article for the very claim that he was secluded on an island, you may as well trust what it says immediately thereafter:

> During this period, he concentrated his studies on the Zohar and the works of earlier Kabbalists. He was also particularly interested in his contemporary, Kabbalist Moses Cordovero. It was at this time that Luria wrote his commentary on the Sifra Di-Zenivta section of the Zohar. Luria believed that deceased teachers of the past spoke to him and that he had frequent interviews with Elijah the prophet.

Comment: But it doesn't say "while on the island"....